# SSL for custom client domains

Tags: ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I have an app (hosted in heroku) where customers have an individual subdomain e.g. `client1.myapp.com`, `client2.myapp.com` I am using a wildcard SSL cert here.

If however a client wants to use their own custom domain e.g. `CNAME` `app.client1.com`

How can i automatically provide an SSL cert (I'm guessing using Lets Encrypt) for the client without them providing me a certificate to upload in a similar way to firebase etc.. provides SSL certs for  domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `app.client1.com` is reachable from the internet, you are free to set up a [lets-encrypt](/questions/tagged/lets-encrypt) certificate.

If your applications run on `unix-like` system, then the [cerbot docs](https://certbot.eff.org/) describe all the steps for automating the renewal.

You basically have to set up a [cronjob](/questions/tagged/cronjob) that launches the renewal command.
You can edit the crons in you linux machine with the command `crontab -e` and place something like this at the end of the file:

```
0 15 1 * * certbot renew
```

This will run the command the first day of each month and attempt the renewal of your certificate. Check [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) if you need different settings.

If you want to call the `cerbot` command from a custom script, you can add such script to your cronjob (and save the output to a custom file).

E.g:

```
0 15 1 * * python cert_autorenew.py >> cron.log 2>&1
```

---

Keep in mind that if you want a certificate for `app.client1.com`, then the renewal request you send, must resolve to the server `app.client1.com`.
That's how you demonstrate the control over your domain to `letsencrypt`.

Comment: @BenFlowers, wow glad I helped! please note that wildcards domains should be soon (or already) available: https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the new application in Heroku/new domain is directed to Heroku app, they will take care of the SSL Certificates for you, as long as you run the application on a paid dyno. Which you should as its a client's application!

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

> Heroku provides free Automated Certificate Management (ACM) for all
>   applications running on paid dynos. With ACM, Heroku automatically
>   provisions and renews SSL certificates for your application. If you
>   prefer to upload your own certificate manually, follow the steps in
>   this article.

You only have to make an application in Heroku, upgrade the dyno and configure the custom domain name (app.client1.com) for the application, following instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains